# Access linked table only shows one to one relationship

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have Access table linked to SQL Server backend. I am converting some of my MS Access queries to SQL Server views. In the design view of the query (view) in SQL Server, I can see that some joined tables have one-to-many relationships and some have one-to-one relationships. However, when I open the queries in MS Access, every single relationship shows a one-to-one relationship.

There is also no database diagram in MS Access as it is linked tables. Due to this reason, the MS Access query is returning fewer records than the SQL Server view does. I want some of the query to remain in MS Access, but since no relationship is present in linked tables, does this mean I have to convert every single query to a SQL Server view?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the display of related tables in the front end really does not matter.

The diagram is really only there for your convenience. What it shows really does not necessary reflect what relationships you have on sql server.

And in the past, that relationship diagram NEVER EVER had ANY effect on the number of rows returned when you build a query in Access.

When you use the Access query builder, then you can make and choose ANY relationship between any tables you want – even ones that don’t make sense.

The front end cannot enforce any kind of relationships on SQLServer, since if front ends could, then what would happen with 5 different front ends, each with different relationships defined?

As a result, SQLServer ignores the relationships you see in Access. In fact, this ALSO applies when using an Access back end. You ALWAYS define the relationships on the database side – not the front end.

About the only real advantage of the defined relationships is that some of the form wizards can use the diagram to help you. And if you fire up the Access query builder and drop in some tables – then the tables will draw (setup) the joins for you based on the relationship window. However, even then, you can delete the join lines, and connect the tables anyway you want – including nonsense joins.

So when you use a web site to connect to amazon.com, your web browser or “client side” computer cannot dictate to the server the enforced relationships – nor can an Access client, or vb.net, or FoxPro when it connects to sql server. You can ONLY define the relationships on the server side – the client can’t do anything at all to change the rules you setup sql server side.

When you link Access tables to SQLServer, you will NOT see the relationships appear in the relationship window.

Of course in the query builder, you will see relationships, but they are not enforced relatonships. You can and always build any kind of join(s) you want in the query builder. How  you set such a query has ZERO to do with enforced relationships in the relatonships window.

So you can choose any join between the tables you want with the query builder in Access – including joins that don’t make sense at all.

If you have migrated data to SQLServer, then your existing un-touch queries (Access side) should continue to return the same results.

And the diagrams you have on SQLServer (and the defined relationships DO NOT come down to the client-side diagram).

If you building a view on SQLServer, then you have to pay close attention to how you build that view, especially left vs “normal” or so called inner joins.

I have been migrating Access databases to sql server for 15+ years, and I never had an Access query return different results after a migration. Test the Access query, it should return the same results as before.

Now of course if you converting the query to a view, then all bets are off, since you now re-writing a query in a different dialect and version of sql – and close attention is required in that case. However, even after moving a query to SQLServer, it is rather rare that you get different results.

So even without sql server, the relationships diagram window had NOTHING to do with how you build a query in the query builder. The relationships you setup don't change how your queries work. The enforced relationships will prevent you from say adding an invoice to the invoice table without setting the "customer" that record belongs to (in the customer table). However, the query builder will not prevent you from writing bad sql - that includes SQLServer, or the Access query builder - they are not really affected in any way by the enforced relationships.

You can write bad sql on both sides (SQL or Access). And by "bad" sql, that would be sql that does not reflect your established and assumed relationships between tables.